# Javascript to change css values for a mobile display

Tags: javascript, css, mobile, nav

I am trying to make a mobile nav button change the menu display from display:none; to display:block; when clicked and then from display:block; to display:none; when clicked again. It works switching from display:none; to display:block; but not from display:block; to display:none;

I am still relatively new to working with javascript, I did try to search around for my answer (i feel it might be out there somewhere), but unless I was implementing some of the other code i found wrong I was not able to get it to function. below is my original attempt at coding it. Thanks for the help

```
var hidden = true;

if (hidden == true) {
   $('a.hamburger').click(function() {
    hidden = false;
    document.getElementById('navigation').style.display = "block";
    document.getElementById('header-menu').style.height = "370px";
    });
} else if (hidden != true) {
$('a.hamburger').click(function() {
    hidden = true;
    document.getElementById('navigation').style.display = "none";
    document.getElementById('header-menu').style.height = "78px";
});
};
```

Answer (score 0):

The correct way of hiding and showing an element in jquery is to use `.hide()` and `.show()`

Example:

```
$('#id').hide(); 

$('#id').show();
```

Or alternatively

```
$("#id").css("display", "none");

$("#id").css("display", "block");
```

Answer (score 0):

Or you could use jQuery's `.toggle()`. Also, I'm not sure whether it is for some reason a conscious choice to mix your jQuery with vanilla JS, but here is a purely jQuery solution:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('a.hamburger').click(function() {
        $('#navigation').toggle();
        if ($('#navigation').is(':visible')) {
            $('#header-menu').css('height', '370');
        } else {
           $('#header-menu').css('height', '');
        }  
    });
});
```

Here's a [working example](http://jsfiddle.net/Sk2vC/1/).

Answer (score 0):

Thanks guys for the answers, i was waiting for an email alert that i had responses but never received one so i had asked a friend for help this morning and figured out the problem is that i had 2 click functions when there only needs to be one, here's what worked out:

```
var $isHidden = true;

$('a.hamburger').click(function() { 


     if ($isHidden == true){

    document.getElementById('navigation').style.display = "block";
    document.getElementById('header-menu').style.height = "370px";
    $isHidden = false;

} else {


    document.getElementById('navigation').style.display = "none";
    document.getElementById('header-menu').style.height = "78px";
    $isHidden = true;
 };
 });
```